# How can I use a nullable int or a NSInteger pointer?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, casting

I need a value to be calculated in it's getter method if it isn't set already. I prefer to use a `nullable int` construction, so I don't need another `bool` to check if it's already been calculated.

My first hunch was to go for a `NSInteger *`. I can check if it's NULL and otherwise set a value to it. But I don't know if it's possible, since I can't really get a value assigned to it.

```
    if (!value)
    {
        value = [self calcValue]; 
    }
    return value;
```

This leads to `Assignment makes pointer from integer without cast` and `Return makes integer from pointer without a cast`.

How would I assign a `int` to a `NSInteger *`?
How would I cast a `NSInteger *` to a `int`?

Or: what is a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `NSInteger` is actually an `int`. You're looking for `NSNumber`, which lets you treat numbers as objects.